# Why are "if elif else" statements virtually never in table format?

Tags: coding-style

```
if   i>0 : return sqrt(i)  
elif i==0: return 0  
else     : return 1j * sqrt(-i)
```

VS

```
if i>0:  
   return sqrt(i)  
elif i==0:  
   return 0  
else:  
   return 1j * sqrt(-i)
```

Given the above examples, I don't understand why I virtually never see the first style in code bases. To me, you turn the code into a tabular format that shows clearly what you want. First column can virtually be ignored. Second column identifies the condition and the third column gives you the output you want. It seems, at least to me, straight-forward and easy to read. Yet I always see this simple kind of case/switch situation come out in the extended, tab indented format. Why is that? Do people find the second format more readable?

The only case where this could be problematic is if the code changes and gets longer. In that case, I think it's perfectly reasonable to refactor the code into the long, indented format. Does everyone do it the second way simply because it's the way it always was done? Being a devil's advocate, I guess another reason might be because people find two different formats depending upon complexity of the if/else statements to be confusing? Any insight would be appreciated.

Comment: Because people find the 2nd option more readable?

Comment: The use case of mutually-exclusive branches that all return a value of the same type doesn't come up often in imperative languages compared to branches that may not return values, might span multiple lines and probably have side effects. If you looked at functional programming languages you'd see code that resembles your first example much more often.

Comment: @horta "The only case where this could be problematic is fi the code changes and gets longer." -- You should **NEVER** assume that a piece of code won't be changed. Code refactoring takes up a large majority of a software's lifecycle.

Comment: @Doval I don't even mean for return value. Assigning a variable or anything else that's short and doesn't run off the right side of the screen.

Comment: Consistency is the most important thing. Your example adds an exception to what I otherwise expect these blocks to look like. Why should I mentally deal with this exception, when the code could just look like all the other code?

Comment: @GManNickG You would think there'd always be one way to do things in programming languages then, but there's not. There's often many. I will agree though, there is something to be said for consistency. I guess I'm just thinking readability would be a valuable trade-off for consistency if it can help people understand the code faster/better. Maybe that's not the case.

Comment: @horta: Having "multiple ways to do something" is not the same as picking one way of formatting code and sticking with it. And you're missing the point: consistency *is* readability. You seem to be taking as axiom that the tabular format is more readable and looking for reasons why it's not used. Rather, because it's completely different from most other formats it makes me take longer to understand what I'm reading; if it had just taken the form as all the other if statements, it would be easier to read.

Comment: @GManNickG I get you. You've learned it one way and now there's one way to do it. It makes it readable to you.

Comment: @horta: Nothing to do with me. It's the code. In the context of the codebase I'm reading, I want to see if statements (and other language constructs) consistently formatted, without any edge cases. It's not that I learned to read code in a particular way, I *can* read either just fine, but it's more readable if everything is the same. Again, not the same to me, the same to the rest of the code.

Comment: Also, most debuggers are line based. Can't put a breakpoint on a statement that's inside an `if` if it's on the same line.

Comment: one simple argument: when you add a second instruction, if written in the second format, the diff on your vcs will only be one line, very easy to understand for whoever reviews the change. with the first format, it is on 3 lines, with significantly more effort to understand that it is just an extra instruction.

Comment: also, your code looks like python, there are well-defined code style for python that allow everyone to quickly get an understanding of the code structure. Many languages have such conventions

Comment: Just a little point: if you had to add a slightly longer `elif` clause (like `i==1 and j==0`) after you wrote the code, you would have to re-inline everything to match the longer clause.

Comment: Personally, I prefer code that looks like prose, and I prefer to use tables for tabular data. The tabular layout of code feels old-fashioned and restricted to me, and a bit foreign.

Comment: @EricKing I don't know of much, if any, prose that has paragraphs sizes of 1-4 words.

Comment: @horta Maybe not, but you missed the point. Prosaic code is more readable, to many, than tabular code. For most, tables are for data.

Comment: @EricKing Do you have data to support this hypothesis? "Prosaic code is more readable, to many, than tabular code."   
Code *is* data. If the data fits well in a table, it would make sense to use a table. Also, tables are prosiac code. They're just well organized prosiac code.

Comment: @horta I'm expressing my opinion, the opinion of those I have worked with, and the majority opinion (as it seems) of the responders to this post. I don't have nor need data to support what isn't a hypothesis. And if you think code and data are the same thing, then no doubt we disagree about that, too.

Comment: @EricKing I see. Code is simply a different kind of data from my perspective.

Comment: because (a) it's a pain to maintain after refactorings (b) only makes sense if you are using a monospace font (c) tbh I don't see a readability improvement.

Comment: @ThanosTintinidis Weird, I didn't think any programmers would use non-monospace font but after a little research, apparently some do. It's just not common:
http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/5473/does-anyone-prefer-proportional-fonts

Comment: When the code becomes too long for a single line, you could just wrap it up into a private method.

Comment: I think we should paint the bike shed blue.

Comment: Because we're making software, not ASCII-art?

Comment: One reason could be the fact that the first version looks so ugly it makes you wanna cry. :P Moreover, I agree with @MarkKCowan that it's not ASCII art.

Comment: As many others have stated; linebreaks are (mostly) easier to read, work better with vcs merging and debuggers. There is however one case where I prefer tabular style - if I have a big switch (or if/elif) statement (typically >= 5 options) that affect mostly the same variables or functions, I find it more compact and readable to put everything on one line (as long as there is only one or two statements in each case) instead of expanding downwards  and filling the entire screen with repetitive "noise".

Comment: The first example really breaks down once you need to have more than a single statement in any branch.  Standard tab-indented formatting works better in that case.  And then if you're going to tab-indent complex `if/else` statements it doesn't make sense to have a completely different style that's used for simpler `if/else` statements.

Answer (score 93, accepted):

One reason may be that you're not using languages where it's popular.

A few counter-examples:

Haskell with guards and with patterns:

```
sign x |  x >  0        =   1
       |  x == 0        =   0
       |  x <  0        =  -1

take  0     _           =  []
take  _     []          =  []
take  n     (x:xs)      =  x : take (n-1) xs
```

Erlang with patterns:

```
insert(X,Set) ->
    case lists:member(X,Set) of
        true  -> Set;
        false -> [X|Set]
    end.
```

Emacs lisp:

```
(pcase (get-return-code x)
  (`success       (message "Done!"))
  (`would-block   (message "Sorry, can't do it now"))
  (`read-only     (message "The shmliblick is read-only"))
  (`access-denied (message "You do not have the needed rights"))
  (code           (message "Unknown return code %S" code)))
```

Generally I see the table format is pretty popular with functional languages (and in general expression based ones), while breaking the lines is most popular in others (mostly statement based).

Comment: I upvoted this and generally agree, but feel obligated to point out that 1. All of these are trivial returns 2. Haskellers are fond of comically short identifiers in addition to the terseness of the language itself and 3. Functional languages tend to be expression based, and even imperative languages have different standards for expressions than statements. If the OP rewrote the original example as function applications he might get different advice...

Comment: @JaredSmith Thanks for the expression/statement based split - I think it may be even more fitting than functional/imperative. Than again ruby is almost expression based and doesn't use that convention often. (exceptions to everything) Regarding points 1 and 2, I find 50%+ of real Haskell code to be "trivial returns" that are just parts of something bigger - it's just how that code is written - not only in examples here. For example close to half of the functions [here](https://github.com/yesodweb/shakespeare/blob/master/Text/Hamlet.hs) are one just one/two liners. (some lines use table layout)

Comment: Yes. I'm not a Haskeller but do some ocaml and find that pattern matching tends to be a lot more concise than logically equivalent switches, and polymorphic functions cover a lot of that ground anyways. I imagine Haskell's type classes would expand that coverage even further.

Comment: I think it's the pattern case syntax that promotes that. Because it's more concise and usually closer to a short switch-case, it's easier to express as one-liners. I frequently do this with short switch-case statements as well for similar reasons. Literal `if-else` statements are still usually spread across multiple lines when not effectively a simple ternary, though.

Comment: @viraptor Technically the other 50%- of haskell code is "non-trivial returns" because all haskell functions are functionally pure and can't have side effects. Even functions that read from and print to the command line are just lengthy return statements.

Comment: Even in non-functional languages (C, Java), it's not uncommon to format simple case statements in a tabular way, one per line, like your elisp example. But switch/case is not quite the same as if / elif / else.

Comment: @LarsH The question text mentions switch/case as well, claiming they're just as uncommon - that's why I included them.

Comment: You're right. I had missed that. Although it seems that the OP only uses "this simple kind of case/switch situation" to refer to the original if/elif/else example. So I wonder to what degree he really meant it.

Answer (score 133):

It's more readable. A few reasons why:

- Nearly every language uses this syntax (not all, *most* - your example appears to be Python, though)
- [isanae pointed out in a comment](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/325845/why-are-if-elif-else-statements-virtually-never-in-table-format/325848?noredirect=1#comment692715_325845) that most debuggers are line based (not statement based)
- It starts looking even more ugly if you have to inline semicolons or braces
- It reads top to bottom more smoothly
- It looks *horribly unreadable* if you have anything other than trivial return statements

  - Any indenting meaningful syntax is lost when you skim code as the conditional code is no longer visually separated (from [Dan Neely](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/325845/why-are-if-elif-else-statements-virtually-never-in-table-format/325848?noredirect=1#comment692851_325848))
  - This will be particularly bad if you continue to patch/add items into the 1-line if statements
- It's only readable if all your if checks are about the same length
- It means you cannot format complicated if statements into multiline statements, they will *have* to be oneliners
- I am far more likely to notice bugs/logicflow when reading vertically line by line, not trying to parse multiple lines together
- Our brains read narrower, taller text MUCH faster than long, horizontal text

The minute you try to do any of this you will end up rewriting it into multiline statements. Which means you just wasted time!

Also people inevitably add something like:

```
if i>0:  
   print('foobar')
   return sqrt(i)  
elif i==0:  
   return 0  
else:  
   return 1j * sqrt(-i)
```

It doesn't take very often doing this before you decide this format is a lot better than your alternative. Ah, but you could inline it all in one line!  *enderland dies on the inside*.

Or this:

```
if   i>0 : return sqrt(i)  
elif i==0 and bar==0: return 0  
else     : return 1j * sqrt(-i)
```

Which is really, really annoying. No one likes formatting things like this.

And last, you will start the holy war of "how many spaces for tabs" problem. What renders perfectly on your screen as a table format may not render on mine depending on settings.

Readability should not depend on IDE settings anyways.

Comment: Do people not use monospaced font when writing code? And yeah I suppose I forgot that there is the holy war of tabs vs spaces.

Comment: And obviously I wouldn't format things the second way you show, so why would you use that as a counter?

Comment: @horta because you will have to _convert_ it if you do format it your first way, initially? I'm all about minimizing work for future enderland. Making pretty whitespace tables and counting spaces and tabs to update the visual formatting when I might add some logic to an if check isn't fun at all (ignoring the readability implications).

Comment: So you wouldn't update the format because... you can't be bothered? As Art said, code is read many times and written once, why wouldn't you write it to be as readable as possible?

Comment: @horta He's not necessarily saying he wouldn't fix it, he's saying he'd have to fix it, and that's a lot of time spent on tedious formatting, rather than on programming.

Comment: @horta no, I'm saying if I update a single if statement I now have to play a formatting game making the table look pretty for the _entire_ if block. Aint no one got time for dat.

Comment: @enderland Interesting. That's where our viewpoints differ it appears. I would have thought readability would be the cornerstone for good code.

Comment: @horta: IMHO *your way* is often less readable, and is definitely a lot more annoying to format. Also, it can only be used when the "ifs" are small one liners, which is a seldom case. Lastly, it's somehow not nice, IMHO, to carry two kind of "if" formattings around because of this.

Comment: @dagnelies The question is *why* do you think it's less readable? Tables were invented for a reason. Short case/switch statements like this are a data type perfectly fit for a table. Is it simply that that's the way you've always seen if/else statements written? Or is there something else that you like about it?

Comment: @dagnelies Thanks for your edit. It clarifies a lot of your thinking around it. Two different hammers can be worse than one; agreed.

Comment: @horta I added a few reasons why inline stuff is less readable.

Comment: @enderland Thanks for the updates. Isn't code that needs to be patched a lot by definition poor code? That seems to be the crux of the issue. The multi-line method is geared towards allowing many code-monkeys to hack at it. Good readable code imho shouldn't need endless patching. Keep in mind, I'm not saying this format should be used for all if statements, only short succinct ones that the original developer designed to not need hack upon hack to make work.

Comment: @horta you seem to be blessed with working on systems where requirements, systems, APIs, and user needs never change. You lucky soul.

Comment: @enderland Heh, if only. I just think underlying substructures should be coded well so that code changes are minimal or do happen in multiline if statements. As I said, I'm not against multiline if statements, just when they turn a table of data into a stream of paragraphs 1 word long.

Comment: I'd add: any small change in a single condition may require reformatting the others to match the `:` position -> doing a diff in a CVS it suddenly becomes more difficult to understand what is actually changin. This is also true for condition vs body. Having them on separate lines means that if you change only one of them the diffs clearly show that only the condition changed, not the body.

Comment: @Bakuriu Interesting point that no one else has brought up; something for me to noodle on. Thanks!

Comment: "What renders perfectly on your screen as a table format may not render on mine depending on settings. " - use soft tabs, period. AKA, the tab key inserts two/three/four space characters.

Comment: "Our brains read narrower, taller text MUCH faster than long, horizontal text" - I take it you've never looked at code written in a functional programming language then. :-P

Comment: @JanDvorak -erm, what if I want to view the code with a tab size of 6. But you want to see it with a tab size of 4. You didn't "solve" anything, you literally just said "use spaces" ignoring _why_ tabs are used.

Comment: Hence, holy war. Which is the True way of the Church of Programming isn't pertinent here, only that it is an issue caused by this.

Comment: @Vld no, I didn't say "use spaces", I said "use soft tabs". As of why tabs are used, it's that you don't have to mash the space key multiple times in a row.

Comment: @JanDvorak - does that output spaces? Yes. Then you are saying "use spaces". The reason for using tabs is not and has never been "oh, I need to press it less times than the space key". Soft tabs do not do what tab characters do. Which is exactly my example from before - if I favour width of 6 spaces, then, what, are you going to press tab one and a half times for me? Or is it more sensible for me to change my settings and not affect you in any way? That's what tabs do.

Comment: 'you are saying "use spaces"' - figuratively, maybe. Literally, no. But hard tabs become an issue as soon as you want to align something, be it a comment or (god forbid) table formatted code.

Comment: The point isn't tabs vs spaces. The point is writing code with inline if statements will cause people using one or the other problems. That holy war has been going on for decades and is not going to be solved here.

Comment: Upvoting for your last point of "humans read tall, short text quicker than wide text".

Comment: When the code becomes too long for a single line, you could just wrap it up into a private method.

Comment: +1 for "Our brains read narrower, taller text MUCH faster than long, horizontal text" - That's why newspapers have had columns... for ever. Oh yeah, does anyone remember what a newspaper is?   And this is why all really long lines in any programming language make me shudder.

Comment: Another point... when the `elif` expression is not related to the `if` expression. `if (i >0) doA();elif (i==0) doB(); else doC();` may make some sense in ideal situation (the optimal case being a `switch` statement). But `if (i>0) doA(); elif (isPrime(z)) doB(); else doC()` is *less* readable as a table than as usually written.

Comment: You can solve (specifically) the tab width problem by never using tabs to align code inline, only to indent to the right level.  Line up with tabs using tabs, and with everything else using spaces.

Answer (score 54):

I am a firm believer in 'code is read many times, written few -- so readability is very important.'

A key thing that helps me when I read other people's code is that is follows the 'normal' patterns that my eyes are trained to recognize. I can read the indented form most easily because I've seen it so many times that it registers almost automatically (with little cognitive effort on my part). It's not because it's 'prettier' -- it's because it follows the conventions that I'm used to. Convention beats 'better' ...

Comment: Relevant: http://thecodelesscode.com/case/94

Comment: This explains why people are conservative. It does not explain why people chose to write their code a certain way to begin with.

Comment: The question was 'why do I see this often', not where did this style come from. Both questions are interesting; I tried to answer the one I thought was being asked.

Answer (score 16):

Along with the other drawbacks already mentioned, tabular layout increases the odds of version control merge conflicts requiring manual intervention.

When a block of tabularly alined code needs to be realigned, the version control system will treat each of those lines as having been modified:

```
diff --git a/foo.rb b/foo.rb
index 40f7833..694d8fe 100644
--- a/foo.rb
+++ b/foo.rb
@@ -1,8 +1,8 @@
 class Foo

   def initialize(options)
-    @cached_metadata = options[:metadata]
-    @logger          = options[:logger]
+    @metadata = options[:metadata]
+    @logger   = options[:logger]
   end

 end
```

Now suppose that in the mean time, in another branch, a programmer has added a new line to the block of aligned code:

```
diff --git a/foo.rb b/foo.rb
index 40f7833..86648cb 100644
--- a/foo.rb
+++ b/foo.rb
@@ -3,6 +3,7 @@ class Foo
   def initialize(options)
     @cached_metadata = options[:metadata]
     @logger          = options[:logger]
+    @kittens         = options[:kittens]
   end

 end
```

Merging that branch will fail:

```
wayne@mercury:/tmp/foo$ git merge add_kittens
Auto-merging foo.rb
CONFLICT (content): Merge conflict in foo.rb
Automatic merge failed; fix conflicts and then commit the result.
```

If the code being modified had not used tabular alignment, the merge would have succeeded automatically.

(This answer was "plagiarized" from [my own article](http://wconrad.github.io/20150627/tabular-alignment-antipattern.html) discouraging tabular alignment in code).

Comment: Interesting, but isn't this a failing of merge tools? Specifically git in this case? This is a datapoint towards convention being the easy way to go. To me, it's something that could be improved upon (from the tool side).

Comment: @horta For the merge tool to modify white space in a way that doesn't almost always break the code, it will have to understand in what ways it can modify white space without changing the meaning of the code.  It will also have to understand the particular tabular alignment being used.  That will be not only language dependent (Python!), but probably require the tool to understand the code to some degree.  On the other hand, line based merging can be done without AI, and quite often does not even break the code.

Comment: Gotcha. So as mentioned elsewhere in the comments, until we have IDE's or programming input formats that incorporate tables directly into the format, tooling problems will always be there just making life difficult for those of us who prefer tables.

Comment: @horta Correct.  Most of my objections to tabular alignment in code could go away with sufficiently advanced tools.

Answer (score 8):

Tabular formats can be very nice if things always fit within the allotted width.  If something exceeds the allotted width, however, then it often becomes necessary to either have part of the table that isn't lined up with the rest of it, or else adjust the layout of everything else in the table to fit match the long item.

If source files were edited using programs that were designed to work with tabular-format data and could handle overly long items by using a smaller font size, splitting them into two lines within the same cell, etc. then it might make sense to use tabular formats more often, but most compilers want source files that are free of the kinds of markup that such editors would need to store in order to maintain formatting.  Using lines with variable amounts of indent but no other layout isn't as nice as tabular formatting in the best case, but it doesn't cause nearly as many problems in the worst case.

Comment: True. I have noticed the text editor I use (vim) has horrible support for tabular formatting or even wide text. I haven't seen other text-editors do much better.

Answer (score 6):

There is the 'switch' statement that provides this kind of thing for special cases, but I guess that's not what you're asking about.

I have seen if statements in table format, but there has to be a large number of conditions to make it worthwhile. 3 if statements are best shown in the traditional format, but if you had 20, then its much easier to display them in a big block that's formatted to make it clearer.

And there's the point: clarity. If it makes it easier to see (and your first example is not easy to see where the : delimiter is) then format it to suit the situation. Otherwise, stick with what people expect, as that's always easier to recognise.

Comment: OP appears to be using Python, so no `switch`.

Comment: "3 if statements are best shown in the traditional format, but if you had 20" ... then you have bigger issues to be thinking about!  : )

Comment: @GrimmTheOpiner If you're writing a language parser or AST stringifier, that's a very possible thing to deal with. For example, I once contributed to a JavaScript parser where I split up a function with 15-20 cases, one for each expression type. I segmented most cases off to their own functions (for a notable perf boost), but the long `switch` was a necessity.

Comment: @JaredSmith: Apparently `switch` is evil, but instantiating a dictionary then performing a lookup on it in order to do trivial branching isn't evil...

Comment: @MarkKCowan I was merely making an observation, not a judgement. I am a huge fan of `switch`, as I frequently have lots of empty-case fall-thrus and I fail to see how the `if (a || b || c || ....` is better.

Comment: @JaredSmith: sorry, my sarcasm didn't go through there - I was agreeing with you

Comment: @MarkKCowan oh I caught the sarcasm but thought you were using it to mock me. lack of context on the internet and whatnot.

Answer (score 1):

Tabular layout can be useful in few limited cases, but there are few times it is useful with if.

In simple cases ?: may be a better choice.
In medium cases a switch is often a better fit (if your language has one). In complicated cases you might find that a call tables are a better fit.

There have been many times when refactoring code that I have rearranged it to be tabular to make it's patern obvious. It is seldom the case that I leave it that way in that in most cases there is a better way to solve the problem once you understand it. Occasionally a coding practice or layout standard prohibits it, in which case a comment is useful.

There was some questions about `?:`. Yes it is the ternary operator (or as I like to think of it the value if). on first blush this example is a little complicated for ?: (and overusing ?: does not help readability but hurts it), but with some thought The example can be rearranged as below, But I think in this case a switch is the most readable solution.

```
if i==0: return 0
return i>0?sqrt(i):(1j*sqrt(-i))
```

Comment: You may have to make it clear what "?:" is for the uninitiated (for instance, with an example, possibly related to the question).

Comment: I'm assuming that's the ternary operator. I feel like that's shunned for the good reason that the ternary operator tends to rearrange the standard if, do stuff, else, do other stuff format that people see day in and day out and therefore can read easily.

Comment: @PeterMortensen: If the uninitiated don't know what this means, they should stay away from the code until they asked the obvious question and learned.

Comment: @horta Ternary is `if ? do stuff : do other stuff`. Same order as an if/else.

Comment: @Navin Ah, maybe it's just a failure of the language I use most (python).
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/394809/does-python-have-a-ternary-conditional-operator

Comment: @horta Yeah, Python's ternaries are a little weird. Every other language uses the if/else format.

Answer (score 1):

If your expression really is that easy most programming languages offer the ?: branching operator:

```
return  ( i > 0  ) ? sqrt( i)
      : ( i == 0 ) ? 0
        /* else */ : 1j * sqrt( -i )
```

This is a short readable tabular format. But the important part is: I see at one glance what the "major" action is. This is a return statement! And the value is decided by certain conditions.

If on the other hand you have branches which execute different code, I find it a lot more readable to indent these blocks. Because now there are different "major" actions depending on the if-statement. In one case we throw, in one case we log and return or just return. There is a different program flow depending on the logic, so code-blocks encapsulate the different branches and make them more prominent for the developer (e.g. speed-reading a function to grasp the program flow)

```
if ( i > 0 )
{
    throw new InvalidInputException(...);
}
else if ( i == 0 )
{
    return 0;
}
else
{
    log( "Calculating sqrt" );
    return sqrt( -i );
}
```

Comment: Actually, I find your "short readable tabular format" quite a nightmare to read, while the format proposed by OP is perfectly fine.

Comment: @MatteoItalia how about this edited version ?

Comment: Sorry, still worse; I think that it comes from the fact that the `?` and `:` are harder to spot than the `if`/`else` keywords and/or due to the added "noise" of the symbols.

Comment: @MatteoItalia: I've had cases with over hundred different values. The table value makes it possible to check for errors. With multi-line, it's impossible.

Comment: @gnasher729: yes and...? I myself am a strong proponent of the "tabular" format (I use it all the time in my code), I'm just saying that the ternary operator does more harm than good to the cause. `if`/`elif` (or `else if` in C-like languages) is better IMO.

Comment: @gnasher729 - For 100 different "values" I have generally found it to be much better to declare a data structure of each "item" and list it all out as a table in the initialization for an array of these data structures. (Of course language limitations may apply here). If any item requires a "computational" aspect the item structure can contain a pointer or reference to a function to perform the needed action. For may applications this can greatly simplify code and make maintenance much easier.

Comment: @MichaelKaras There was a nice question about this: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/244878/

Answer (score 1):

As enderland has already said, you're assuming you only ever have one "return" as the action, and that you can tag that "return" onto the end of the condition.  I'd like to give some extra detail for why this isn't going to be successful.

I don't know what your preferred languages are, but I've been coding in C for a long time.  There are a number of coding standards around which aim to avoid some standard coding errors by disallowing code constructions which are prone to errors, either in initial coding or during later maintenance.  I'm most familiar with MISRA-C, but there are others, and generally they all have similar rules because they're addressing the same problems in the same language.

One popular error which coding standards often address is this little gotcha:-

```
if (x == 10)
    do_something();
    do_something_else();
```

This does not do what you think it does.  As far as C is concerned, if x is 10 then you call `do_something()`, but then `do_something_else()` gets called *regardless of the value of x*.  Only the action immediately following the "if" statement is conditional.  This may be what the coder intended, in which case there's a potential trap for maintainers; or it may not be what the coder intended, in which case there's a bug.  It's a popular interview question.

The solution in coding standards is to mandate braces around all conditional actions, even if they're single-line.  We now get

```
if (x == 10)
{
    do_something();
    do_something_else();
}
```

or

```
if (x == 10)
{
    do_something();
}
do_something_else();
```

and now it works correctly and is clear for maintainers.

You will notice that this is entirely incompatible with your table-style format.

Some other languages (e.g. Python) looked at this problem and decided that since coders were using whitespace to make layout clear, it would be a good idea to use whitespace instead of braces.  So in Python,

```
if x == 10:
    do_something()
    do_something_else()
```

makes the calls to both `do_something()` and `do_something_else()` conditional on x == 10, whereas

```
if x == 10:
    do_something()
do_something_else()
```

means that only `do_something()` is conditional on x, and `do_something_else()` is always called.

It's a valid concept, and you'll find a few languages use it.  (I first saw it in Occam2, way back when.)  Again though, you can easily see that your table-style format is incompatible with the language.

Comment: I think you missed the point. The issue you speak of is a weird C specific non-standard nightmare that causes the issue you speak of. If coding in C, I would never recommend using the alternate simple if method with the tabular format I suggested. Instead, since you're using C, you would use braces all on the single line. The braces would actually make the table format even more clear because they're acting as delimiters.

Comment: Also, the return statements in this case is just an example. In general, that may be code smell in itself. I'm just referring to the format of simple statements, not necessarily with return statements at all.

Comment: My point was that this makes a table format even more clunky.  Incidentally, it's not C-specific - it's shared by all languages derived from C, so C++, C#, Java and JavaScript all allow the same gotcha.

Comment: I don't mind that it's return statements - I get that your intention is to show simple statements.  But it becomes more cumbersome.  And of course as soon as any statement becomes non-simple, then you need to change the formatting because a table format is impossible to maintain.  Unless you're doing code obfuscation, long lines of code are a smell in their own right.  (Original limit was 80 chars, these days it's more typically around 130 chars, but the general principle still holds that you shouldn't have to scroll to see the end of the line.)

Answer (score -3):

I don't see anything wrong with the table format. Personal preference, but I would use a ternary like this:

```
return i>0  ? sqrt(i)       :
       i==0 ? 0             :
              1j * sqrt(-i)
```

No need to repeat `return` every time :)

Comment: As mentioned in a few comments, the return statements isn't ideal or the point of the post, simply a chunk of code I found online and formatted a couple ways.

Comment: Python ternaries are `do_something() if condition() else do_something_else()`, not `condition() ? do_something() : do_something_else()`.

Comment: @IsiahMeadows OP never mentioned Python.